# How to render XML template and then use SEND_DATA in Ruby on Rails 3.2.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, send

Can anybodyes help me with XML template rendering and send_data?

I have a controller:

```
def show
  @calculation = Calculation.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @calculation }
    format.xml {send_data( :partial=>show.xml.erb, :filename => "my_file.xml" ) }
    format.pdf { render :format=>false}
  end
end
```

But I have many errors with "stack level too deep"

If I use

```
{send_data( @calculation, :filename => "my_file.xml" ) }
```

I get XML file, but not from my template...

***EDIT:***  I've got a way!

```
format.xml do  
  stream = render_to_string(:template=>"calculations/show" )  
  send_data(stream, :type=>"text/xml",:filename => "test.xml")
end
```

And all works properly!

Comment: Could you post your entire trace?

Comment: SystemStackError in CalculationsController#show

stack level too deep
Rails.root: C:/RubyStack-3.2.5-0/examplexml

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70

Comment: I can have a result in my Chrome with:

    format.xml { render :format=>false}

But only screen, not file to download

Comment: Hey Dmitry, considering posting to your question and marking it as as solution.

Comment: @Dmitry - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Copying the answer from the edited question body in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

```
format.xml do  
  stream = render_to_string(:template=>"calculations/show" )  
  send_data(stream, :type=>"text/xml",:filename => "test.xml")
end
```

~ answer per [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1700247/dmitry)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with Rails 5

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    stream = render_to_string(:template => "calculations/test.xml.builder")
    send_data stream,
              :type => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8;',
              :disposition => "attachment; filename=test.xml"
  end
end
```